# How to better control on automatic HTML indentation

Tags: html, indentation, tidy

I have the below code

```html
$ cat index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.6.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>vue (no tranpile) + bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity= "sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-2">
<div class="col text-center">
<h1>Todo application</h1>
<div id="app"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="module">
 <script type="module">
    import { createApp, ref } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js";

    createApp({
      setup() {
        const newTodo = ref(''); const todos = ref([]);
        function addTodo() {
          if (newTodo.value.trim()) {
            todos.value.push(newTodo.value);
            newTodo.value = '';}}
        return { newTodo, todos, addTodo };
      },
      template: `
        <div>
          <input v-model="newTodo" @keyup.enter="addTodo">
          <button @click="addTodo">Add</button>
          <ul><li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo">{{ todo }}</li></ul>
        </div>`
    }).mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
$
```

I try to get it indented like this (with the  content untouched):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>vue (no tranpile) + bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h1>Todo application</h1>
          <div id="app"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
    import { createApp, ref } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js";

    createApp({
      setup() {
        const newTodo = ref(''); const todos = ref([]);
        function addTodo() {
          if (newTodo.value.trim()) {
            todos.value.push(newTodo.value);
            newTodo.value = '';}}
        return { newTodo, todos, addTodo };
      },
      template: `
        <div>
          <input v-model="newTodo" @keyup.enter="addTodo">
          <button @click="addTodo">Add</button>
          <ul><li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo">{{ todo }}</li></ul>
        </div>`
    }).mount('#app');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my context online formatters are not an option.

The best I get is with Tidy:

```html
$ tidy -qni -ashtml index.html -o out.html
$ cat out.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.6.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>vue (no tranpile) + bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity=
  "sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <h1>Todo application</h1>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="module">
      import { createApp } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js";
      ...
  </script>
</body>
</html>
$
```

==> No alignement of href, rel, crossorigin, integrity, ... ;(

tidy version:

```
$ tidy -v
HTML Tidy pour Linux version 5.6.0
$ uname -a
Linux spinoza 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

tidy options:

```
$ LANG=en tidy -h | grep -E '\-q |\-n |, \-i'
 -indent, -i                indent element content                            
 -numeric, -n               output numeric rather than named entities         
 -quiet, -q                 suppress nonessential output
$
```

Comment: Good idea, that looks great. Update your Q to show output from `tidy -v ; uname -srv` . (Not sure this is possible). Good luck.

Comment: I can't find the `-s` option in the tidy v5.6.0 man page. Using `-n` doesn't seem to make sense and I don't see what `-ashtm` would do, but kudos for experimenting! Maybe `--indent=auto` would give a diferent result? Did you try the sample tidy.conf file at http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/ ? Good luck.

Comment: From the FAQ : "indent-attributes is a flag that, when set, tells Tidy to put each attribute on a new line."

Comment: A whole bunch of `indent-*` options listed at https://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.6.0.html#PrettyPrintHeader . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Getting close, this is what I get with (not bad):

```
:'<,'>!tidy -qni -ashtml --indent-attributes yes -w 140
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="generator"
        content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.6.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>vue (no tranpile) + bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <h1>Todo application</h1>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="module">
  import { createApp } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again from the doc "Use the option indent-spaces to control the number of spaces or tabs output per level of indent, and indent-with-tabs to specify whether spaces or tabs are used." I assume your remaining problem is that data under `<script` does not align at the end of the word `<script` ? I haven't looked for others. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use online HTML formatters like HTML Formatter, HTML Beautifier, or Online HTML Editor.
•   Copy your HTML code.
•   Paste it into one of these online tools.
•   Click the “Format” or “Beautify” button.
•   The tool will automatically format your code with proper indentation.